# Suppressing ORA-06512 Exception stack information in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am using user defined exception for no_data_found but still am seeing the **ORA-06512** stack information with user defined exception **ORA-20106**

```
ORA-20106: Problem in loading Affected Circle data
ORA-06512: at "SRUSER.ADD_AFFECTEDCIRCLE", line 30
```

How can I suppress  ORA-06512 stack information?

This is my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_circleID 
( v_circle_code  vf_circle.circle_code%TYPE)
RETURN vf_circle.circle_id%TYPE
IS
    return_value  vf_circle.circle_id%TYPE; 
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT circle_id INTO return_value
        FROM vf_circle
        WHERE circle_code = v_circle_code;
   END;
   RETURN return_value;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20102, 'Circle Code is wrong or not available',TRUE);
END get_circleID;
/
```

Comment: :Paste your code please

Comment: Lines marked with `ORA-06512` are traceback info.  You can simply read `SQLERRM` to get error message without traceback info.

Comment: @gaurav: I added my code as per your suggestion

Comment: @Egor: When I run the code, it is showing me those error traces in the output

Comment: @Egor: If i change to FALSE, it stops propagating the user execption to parent procedure. but still I am seeing ORA-06512 Error with the user exception which i created.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - in an earlier post OP had indicated he wanted all messages listed and he was told to add the third parameter to RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR.  Frankly I don't think there's a way to avoid the stack tracebacks.

Comment: [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:195612348072)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it a bit odd for someone to request less information in error/exception handling. I usually dump there as much stack trace as possible (more the merrier !). But maybe you're working in a context where there is a legitimate reason.

Are you looking for something like this example ?

```
-- exception types and related error codes encapsulated 
-- into an application specific package
create or replace package expkg is
  dummy_not_found constant number := -20102;
  dummy_not_found_ex exception;
  -- numeric literal required
  pragma exception_init (dummy_not_found_ex, -20102);
  -- helper to hide a bit esoteric string handling
  -- call only in exception handler !
  function get_exception_text return varchar2;
end;
/

create or replace package body expkg is
  function get_exception_text return varchar2 is
  begin
    -- returns only the first line of a multiline string
    return regexp_substr(sqlerrm, '^.+$', 1, 1, 'm');
  end;
end;
/

begin
  declare
    v_dummy dual.dummy%type;
  begin
    select dummy into v_dummy from dual where dummy = 'A';
  exception
    -- convert exception type
    when no_data_found then
      raise_application_error(expkg.dummy_not_found, 'Not A dummy !', true);
  end;
exception
  when expkg.dummy_not_found_ex then
    -- DIY if the default format doesn't fit 
    dbms_output.put_line(expkg.get_exception_text);
end;
/
```

**Output:**

```
ORA-20102: Not A dummy !
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define Pragma exception init to define user defined message and error number.like below

```
    pragma exception_init( Message, Number );
```